# how right use function in include file?

Tags: php, function, include

Good day.

We have 3 files:

1) **index.php**

```
<?php
require_once("functions.php");
$t= new getgunctions;
$t->getgainTpl();
$t->controllerTpl(1);
?>
```

2) **functions.php**

```
<?php
class getgunctions{
  .....
  public function controllerTpl(){
    $this->form();
  }
  private function form(){
    include "form.tpl";
  }
  public function right(){
    echo 'test';
  }
  .....
}

?>
```

3) **form.tpl**

```
<div><?php $this->right(); ?></div>
```

but i get error:  `Using $this when not in object context...`

Tell me please how right use function `right();` in form.tpl?

Comment: You may not use `$this` outside class/object methods

Comment: Try add " $obj = $this; " before include form.tpl, and use $obj->right()

Comment: include  `functions.php` in `form.tpl` and the use class name in  `functions.php` instead of `$this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check files on server. it was worked if you not error in function.php

Answer (score 0):

`$this` returns nothing in your case. So obv. you cant use it.

I dont see much code here, but i suppose that you will need this here:

```
<div><?php $t->right(); ?></div>
```

If this isnt the problem, we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you defined in `functions.php` are global functions, visible in the global scope since they are included outside any namespace or class definition (i'm assuming this from your first snippet), and not class methods. Therefore, to call them you just need to use their name, as in:

```
<div><?php right(); ?></div>
```

This assuming that `form.tpl` is included by some of your latest method calls, for example `$t->getgainTpl();`.

If you want to encapsulate `form()` and `right()` inside the `getgunctions` class, you need to define them as class methods, by modifying or extending `getgunctions`:

```
class getgunctions
{
    // previous code

    public function right()
    {
        // implementation...
    }
}
```

Comment: function in class - i edit question, see again please

Answer (score 0):

This does work principally. Your error must be coming from something else.